# How to avoid question during the Docker build?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I am building an Ubuntu 18.04 based  Docker image. 
It is building ok but before finish I receive in the Powershell  console:

```
Configuring tzdata
------------------
Please select the geographic area in which you live. Subsequent configuration
questions will narrow this down by presenting a list of cities, representing
the time zones in which they are located.
  1. Africa        6. Asia            11. System V timezones
  2. America       7. Atlantic Ocean  12. US
  3. Antarctica    8. Europe          13. None of the above
  4. Australia     9. Indian Ocean
  5. Arctic Ocean  10. Pacific Ocean
Geographic area:
----
```

As I understand it waits some answer from me but I cannot enter any numbers, i.e. no reactions on keyboard. How to avoid this question? May be in I can add a CMD into the dockerfile ?

Comment: What does the Dockerfile look like? Have you tried using a different shell?

Comment: I have copy/pasted the dockerfile

Comment: Try adding `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` before the `apt-get` statements

Comment: Ok, will try and let you know...

Comment: Let me know and I will share at as an answer if it solved the problem

Answer (score 42):

I had the same issue in `Dockerfile`, then I used
`ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` after base image and it works for me:

Example Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me.

```
ENV TZ=Asia/Kolkata \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install tzdata
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `apt` in Docker, but rather `apt-get`. The DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive does not work on `apt` somehow.

In addition, some packages that require such inputs could be recommendations. So add the `--no-install-recommends` option on your `apt-get install -y` runs. E.g

```
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && \
    # To avoid the installation of non essential packages
    apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
    wget git
```

With tzdata, I set the environmental variables below to get it to work:

```
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TZ=Africa/Johannesburg
```